# T/F: The Range of a Linear Transformation must be a subset of the domain.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am having difficulty understanding why it is false. As I understand, the range is the output of everything from the domain into the transformation function, or the result of the domain being outputted to the co-domain via the transformation. Essentially, I cannot think of a counterexample where the range of a linear transformation is not in the domain. I would appreciate if anyone could shed some light on this basic concept that I am struggling with.

Comment: Because the range **of any function** is always a subset of the codomain. Thus, if you have a linear transformation $\;T: V\to W\;$ , its range is a subset (in fact, a subspace) of $\;W\;$ .

Comment: The range of a function is a subset of the codomain.

Comment: Think of a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ through a matrix of transformation $A$. $\mathbb{R}^3$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following example of linear transformation,

> $T:\mathbb R \to {\mathbb R}^2$
>
> $T(x)= (x,0)$

Note that Range of $T$ is {$(x,0):x \in \mathbb R$} which is not a subset of the domain (i.e. $\mathbb R$).

Answer (score 2):

Take $F\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}[x]$ defined by $F(\lambda)=\lambda x$. Its range is a set of polynomials, and therefore it is *not* a subset of $\mathbb R$.